# How to get select2 value in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

I am not able to get the value of select2.
This is my code:

```
<select id="categoryId" class="category"            
                        ng-model="selectedCategory"
                        ng-options="selectedCategories.name for selectedCategories in categories"
                        ng-change="selectedCategory()">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>
```

In my controllers I wrote this:

```
    .....  

  function initializeSelect2 (){
        $category.select2({
                allowClear: true
        });
   }

   $scope.selectedCategory = function (){
        console.log('selectCategory: '+ $scope.selectedCategory);    
   }
```

Comment: you need to use `ui-select2` https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2 which is angular version of `select2`

Comment: Note, that ui-select2 is deprecated and written for select2@~3.4 and might not work with select2@4.0

Answer (score 0):

For versions of Select2 before 4.0.0, it is recommended to drop Select2 and use [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) (**not [ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2)**) which is an AngularJS-native version of Select2. Select2 4.0.0 works with AngularJS though (as much as it needs to), so it is no longer strictly necessary to use ui-select.

The problem here is that the DOM `change` event (which is triggered by Select2) is different from the AngularJS `change` event, which is what you are listening to. The AngularJS `change` event is triggered whenever the value of `ng-model` changes, which in your case might not be when you are expecting it.

Your `ng-model` doesn't contain a dot (`.`) in it, which means that Angular is not going to be able to listen to changes as easily and might never detect them. So that is one easily fixable explanation for why the `ng-change` handler might not be triggered.

The other reason might be that Select2 was half-destroyed in a digest cycle, which would leave Select2's DOM sitting in pieces around the page but the event handlers wouldn't necessarily be working as expected. This would be easily noticeable by the dropdown not opening or closing, so I suspect this might not actually be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the new comers , the quick and dirty solution is to replace attribute ng-value with value and use native javascript to get value and assign it to scope variable.

```
<select id="categoryId" class="category"            
                    ng-model="selectedCategory"
                    ng-change="selectedCategory()">
                    <option ng-repeat="selectedCategories in categories" value="selectedCategories"></option>
</select>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.selectedCategory.name = document.getElementById('categoryId').value;
```